# Docker Container ignores port 80

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

Since I use macvlan network configuration and give every container a different IP, I would like to access the services via port 80 and not the costum port. But this doesn't work for me.

Currently I created the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'

networks:
  dockervlan:
    external: true
    
volumes:
  data:
    
services:
  uptime-kuma:
    image: louislam/uptime-kuma:latest
    container_name: uptime-kuma
    volumes:
      - data:/app/data
    ports:
      - "80:3001" # <Host Port>:<Container Port>
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      dockervlan:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.178.194
```

After that I still be able to access the service via http://192.168.178.194:3001 but not via http://192.168.178.194

Same for portainer:

```
version: '3'

services:
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    container_name: portainer
    ports:
      - 80:9000
      - 8000:8000
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - data:/data
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      dockervlan:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.178.200

networks:
  dockervlan:
    name: dockervlan
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth0
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "192.168.178.0/24"
          ip_range: "192.168.178.192/26"
          gateway: "192.168.178.1"
volumes:
  data:
```

I also tried 3001:80 and 9000:80, which of course didn't work euther.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: So 192.168.178.194 is the ip address of the container, right? And within the container your service is running on port 3001, right? so you can of course access http://192.168.178.194:3001.  But as you are binding the *host's* port 80 to the containers port 3001, you have to use the IP Address of your **host** to access your service on port 80

Comment: The raspberry got the IP 192.168.178.5, so I tried 192.168.178.5:3001 and 192.168.178.5:9000 and expected to access kumo or portainer, but this doesn't work for me either.

Comment: If your host has ipaddress `a.a.a.a` and the container on the on the host has ipaddress `a.a.a.b` and you have a mapping like `porta:portb` you can either use `a.a.a.a:porta` or `a.a.a.b:portb` to access your container, but not `a.a.a.a:portb` or `a.a.a.b:porta` Furthermore, on the same host, you can only bind *one* container to port 80. You seem to want to create bindings `80:3001` and `80:9000` that is not possible ...